# ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider<GroupModel> above this GroupScreen Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that GroupScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  ```
     void _copyGroupId(BuildContext context) {
         GroupModel group = Provider.of<GroupModel>(context, listen: false);
         Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: group.id));
         key.currentState?.showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
         content: Text("Copied!"),
      ));
   }
  ```

  Call the void

  ```
         ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Copy Group Id"),
              onPressed: () => _copyGroupId(context),
            ),
  ```

The groupModel just in case

```
  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

 class GroupModel {
     String id;
     String name;
     String leader;
     List<String> members;
     Timestamp groupCreated;

 GroupModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.leader,
    required this.members,
    required this.groupCreated,
  });

  factory GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({required DocumentSnapshot doc}) {
    return GroupModel(
         id: doc.id,
         name: doc.get("name"),
         leader: doc.get("leader"),
         members: List<String>.from(doc.get("members")),
         groupCreated: doc.get("groupCreated"),
     );
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh umm I solved it. Sorry for the trouble.But I would like to see your opinions

In the main.dart:

```
return  MultiProvider(
   providers: [
    Provider(create: (_) => AuthBloc(uid: '')),
    Provider(create: (_) => GroupModel(id: 'id', name: 'name', leader: 'leader', groupCreated: Timestamp.now(), members: ['members'])),
    Provider(create: (_) => User),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Dover Tree',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.redAccent,
    ),
    home: const LoginScreen(),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).